# Embed HTML to render a simple browser inside swf with StageWebView

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I found a way to do this and it works when tested in Flash (Control+Enter).
But when I export movie clip as swf, the file size is only 2k and doesn't open with Acrobat Reader. This seems to be the best way for me, because then I want to insert the swf in a pdf file. My final intention is basically to have both a youtube playlist and a Facebook comment box embeded inside the pdf.

I'm using Flash CS6 and pasted this code:

```
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.media.StageWebView;
import flash.geom.Rectangle;
import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
import flash.ui.Keyboard;
import flash.desktop.NativeApplication;

//This will return the actual width value of our stage
var wView:int = stage.stageWidth;
//This will return the actual height value of our stage
var hView:int = stage.stageHeight;

//Create a new StageWebView object
var swv:StageWebView = new StageWebView();
//Set the size of StageWebView object created to match the screen size
swv.viewPort = new Rectangle(0,0,wView,hView);

//Load the Google Page
swv.loadURL("https://www.google.com/");
//Show the StageWebView Object
//If you want to hide it, set the stage property to null
swv.stage = this.stage;
```

Comment: StageWebView is only available for AIR runtime.

Comment: ooh... but will I be able to bring it into a pdf though?